# Google Chrome Extension get DOM from another page of the site

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am dveloping my first extension and I am currently getting data from the page but the page is for example: "example.com/my-data" and I need to display this data from "example.com/" to not need go to that page. How can I get the data from the home page?

Comment: Depends on how that data is served. In the simplest case you can use XMLHttpRequest/fetch and DOMParser, the examples are easy to find.

Comment: Yes I injected code to append JSON with info on the DOM and achieved this.